# UIButton has gap

Tags: objective-c, ios

Making a UIButton. for some reason, it has a white gap around it (the grey area is the UIView the button is in):

[image]

code:

```
UIView *photoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, (THUMBNAIL_SIZE) + (PHOTO_VIEWER_OFFSET_COLUM_1 * 2))];
photoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

UIScrollView *myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, photoView.frame.size.height)];
myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50); 
myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:labelFont size:16];
[myButton setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add-report.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.center = CGPointMake(((photoView.frame.size.width - myScrollView.frame.size.width) / 2) + myScrollView.frame.size.width, photoView.frame.size.height / 2);

[photoView addSubview:myButton];
[self.view addSubview:photoView];
```

I dont' want the white buffers space there, but i can't figure out how to get rid of it.

any ideas?

EDIT: if i try to change the background color:

```
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

i get this effect:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the gray bounding frame is part of the button? Is it clickable?

Comment: no, i'm sorry, the grey area is the UIView. the button is the green and the white area. and yes the white area is clickable.

Comment: try `[myButton setImage:...]` instead of setting background image

Comment: i tried that already, doesn't help unforuntantly

Answer (score 0):

It might be the text label that has a white background be default?

Try setting every color to `[UIColor clearColor]` such as `button.background` and `button.titleLabel.background`.

Also try to modify the image view. Maybe it does not scale automatically as expected:

```
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Comment: button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill; didn't do anything

Comment: no, clear color didn't solve it. i added an image to the first post showing what setting the background color does. with clearcolor, there is still the white space between the button and the superview's background color